# How do I apply ast.literal_eval to an entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multithreading, performance

The only way I know to apply ast.literal_eval to an entire dataframe is to loop over each column like so:

```
for col in df.columns:
         df[col] = df[col].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do so like using multiprocessing.Pool or some other way?

Comment: @Karl IIUC that wasn't really the question, OP rather asked if there was a multiprocessing way rather than simple evaluation on all cells with a loop

Comment: "more efficient" is ambiguous and it isn't at all clear why OP expects multiprocessing to be helpful here. If the question is "how do I divide up a task so that I can give separate parts to processes in a `multiprocessing.Pool`?", then that is already nowhere near focused enough - it essentially reduces to "how do I use multiprocessing?". The *standard* way is `.applymap`, as in the linked duplicate and also the answer that was attracted here; if that isn't sufficient then alternative answers *belong on the linked duplicate anyway* (such as the `np.vectorize` approach).

Comment: For sure the question lacks details, but I doubt `applymap` is what OP is looking for ;)

Comment: you need to use lambda inside appy : ```df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))``` or ```df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))```

Comment: So, in the end, this is what worked for me:







`pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([pool.map(ast.literal_eval, df[col]) for col in df.columns]).transpose().astype(np.uint8), columns = df.columns)`

@mozway 

applymap was too slow

Comment: @Amin have you found a question that duplicates the answer you gave as comment? If yes please provide it and I'll update the duplicate link. NB. I know that `applymap` is slow, thus my initial comment ;)